# Unable to delete .zip file from file system

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, nsfilemanager

Unable to delete .zip file from file system.

Error:

```
NSError *error;
BOOL deleted = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[DocumentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[UserDefaults stringForKey:kNCSIOfflineDataFileName]] error:&error];
if (!deleted) {
    DebugLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error);
}
```

Code:

```
NSError *error;
    BOOL deleted = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[UserDefaults stringForKey:kNCSIOfflineDataFilePath] error:&error];
    if (!deleted) {
        DebugLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error);
    }
```

Path is verified:
[image]

Comment: Obviously the path is wrong.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Avi The path is correct! Verified!

Comment: @Avi other files are getting removed without error at same path, only this one file is not being deleted.

Comment: Double-check the capitalization.  The device is case-sensitive, though the simulator (usually) isn't.

Comment: @Avi The path is not hard-coded. The path used for saving the file is the same path used to delete the file.

Comment: Have you been updating this app?  If so the UUID in `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application` will change each time and won't match the value stored in `NSUserDefaults` (which will be migrated over during the update).

Comment: Possible issue as said by @trojanfoe: The path where there is the UUID. How do you retrieve it? You should only get preoccupied by what's after that UUID (`NSDocuments() and your custom path)` in your case. Other possible issue, try with setting replacing in the path `file:///var/mobile` with `file:///private/var/mobile`. I've encountered that issue on a project.

Comment: @trojanfoe I tried this on simulator as well. Also the app is not updated. I am just downloading a file and on a click of button trying to remove it using the same path.

Comment: You are still using a very bad pattern.  Fix that and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storing file paths that include the absolute path to an app's documents folder in `NSUserDefaults` is a very bad idea.

Here's why:

1. The UUID of an app will change when it's updated.
2. iOS will migrate the user defaults during the update.
3. You load the old absolute value and it's no longer pointing to a file.

Instead store just the values *after* the Documents file root and build the full path every time using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`.

Comment: Other files are also there, and they are being removed.

Comment: As mentioned; it's a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar problems before when accessing files via file:/// or URLs.

The best thing I can suggest is to access the Documents Directory path via a string variable, append the string using

```
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:(NSString *)
```

to build a string that represents the file. Then delete using NSFileManager's

```
    removeItemAtPath:(NSString *)
```